# rpm dependency in detail

Tags: openssl, centos, rpm

[update] I think this is a rpm question. So I updated the subject

I'm trying to replace the Redhat's openssl with the up-to-date source package from openssl.org in CentOS 6. When I do a make, many tools generate error messages like:

```
Error: Package: pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-3.e17.x86_64 (@mysever)
Requires: 1ibcrypto.so.10( lib.crypto.so.10)(64bit)
Removing: 1:openss1-libs.1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 (@mysever)      
     libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.1.0g.x86_64 (mybuild-repo) 
     Not found 

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofi1es --nodigest
```

It seems the system does find my newly built rpm, `openssl-libs-1.1.0gx86_64`, which contains an updated libcrypto `/usr/lib64/1ibcrypto.so.11`. But it is not using it to replace `libcrypto.so.10`.

I have also tried to keep using the filename "1ibcrypto.so.10" (without increment the soversion number) in my build and still got the same error.

So, when the package system said "Not found", is there a way to know what's it's looking for? How to specify those in a spec file?

Thanks

[update] I do not know how Redhat built their packages.

Comment: You need to show (1) how you configured and built OpenSSL; and (2) how you configured and built PyOpenSSL. Also, it is usually dangerous to replace the system version of OpenSSL. It often results in a system that will not update or validate packages. It is usually a mistake you make once.

Comment: Do not attempt to replace the system version of openssl for Red Hat. Red Hat modifies the standard openssl for its own reasons/purposes. If you manage to replace it with a stock openssl, you will break your OS. If you want to use a different version, create your version and install it in your own application directory as necessary (along with the libraries) and link your app to those libraries.